# Can't understand the synchronise function for SMPTE/Vegas

Tags: sync

I've tried to understand how to manage SMPTE sync in Vegas.

For that, i've generated and recorded one SMPTE track in a dawn, then i've cut some part of it at various time, export it as wav file and import them in Vegas (like simulating many camera receiving the signal). Projects are set in audio at 48 khz both. FPS in Vegas is set by defaut at 29,970.

[image: Cubase project]

But regarding the part i've cut, the sync work correctly every time and i don't understant why.

Full length part : 3 minuts
First part : start at 60s, 10s -> ko, Vegas SMPT sync set the part start at 90s
Second part : start at 61s, 10s -> ko, Vegas SMPT sync set the part start at 90s
Third part : start at 70s, 10s -> ok
Fourth part : start at 60s, 20s -> ok
Fith part : start at 0s, 60s -> ok
Sixth part : start at 80s, 100s -> ok

If i put the full length with the first and second at same time, it's worst :
First part : start at 60s, 10s -> ko, Vegas SMPT sync set the part start at 9,896s
Second part : start at 61s, 10s -> ko, Vegas SMPT sync set the part start at 19,896s

[image: See the Vegas timeline...]

The files : [All wav files used](https://ufile.io/f/s90vc)

One more strange thing ? if i select first the little part, then the full length part, the synchronization work correctly for the second part (and almost for the third, 60s start point instead of 61 expected)

All other parts works like a charm in sync, no strange time positionning

Any idea what's going wrong ?